# Python unicode csv cyryllic, dont convert

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have a problem with writing cyryllic to csv. I use unicodecsv and next snippet:

```
import unicodecsv

ff = open('test.csv', 'wb+')
writer = unicodecsv.writer(ff, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
writer.writerows([[u'тест', 'aaa', 'nnn']])
ff.close()
```

csv generates well, but than U open it in Microsoft Excel 2011 and I see this:
[image]

Try it in Libre office too, same problem...
OS: Mac os Yosemite

don't work too with utf-8-sig:

```
writer = unicodecsv.writer(ff, encoding='utf-8-sig', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

Comment: what is `print(repr(open('test.csv', 'rb').read()[:11]))`?

Answer (score 1):

Excel likes UTF-8-encoded files to have a BOM (byte order mark) signature.  Use `utf-8-sig` as the encoding instead, else it thinks the file is ANSI-encoded.  "ANSI" is locale-dependent, and is `Windows-1252` on U.S. Windows.

Test source file saved with UTF-8 encoding:

```
#coding:utf8
import unicodecsv

with open('test.csv', 'wb+') as ff:
    writer = unicodecsv.writer(ff, encoding='utf-8-sig', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerows([[u'тест', 'aaa', 'nnn']])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `writer = unicodecsv.writer(ff, encoding='utf-8-sig', delimiter=',', quotechar='"') ` same problem

Comment: @OlegBeat, I just installed `unicodecsv` and tested it.  It opened correctly for me on Windows.  A hex edit of the file shows the BOM was written correctly.  The original encoding of `utf-8` didn't have the BOM and didn't work.  One thing, did you declare the encoding of your source file and actually save the source in that encoding?